# When to and why use em.clear() in MikroOrm

Tags: entitymanager, mikro-orm

I am a little bit confuse about what `em.clear()` does in MikroOrm or any similar entity Manager.
https://mikro-orm.io/docs/entity-manager the link for `clear()` method.

I had seems some of stackoverflow answers regarding general EntityManager said I need to call `clear()` after every `persist/remove and flush` to avoid any memory issue.

To make this question more specific for my case, supposedly I build up a `Graphql` endpoint in my application.
There are some general CRUD functions for users to call, each function will create a `MikroOrm entity` by utilizing some of MikroOrm function like `findOne()`, etc. to do some general CRUD operation on the database.

Does it mean I need to call `clear()` every time after `persist/remove and flush` (if there are some CUD operation) and even reading data only? And what happen if I don't call this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`em.clear()` is for testing purposes, so you can simulate multiple independent requests with single EM instance:

```
const book1 = await em.findOne(Book, 1); // now book 1 will be loaded
const book2 = await em.findOne(Book, 1); // as book 1 is already loaded, this won't query the db
expect(book1).toBe(book2); // and we will get identity here
em.clear(); // but when we clear the identity map
const book3 = await em.findOne(Book, 1); // this will query the db as the state is now gone
expect(book1).not.toBe(book3); // and identity is gone
```

You could achieve the same by using `em.fork()`, having multiple EMs instead of using one.

The memory should be freed automatically during garbage collection, you should not need the `em.clear()` method in regular (app) code. Your application code should be using either `RequestContext` helper or manual forking (see https://mikro-orm.io/docs/identity-map). After the request finishes, there should be no reference to this old context and it should be garbage collected (but keep in mind this happens indeterministically, e.g. when JS engine feels like it :]).

Comment: Thx a lot, Your link also helps me understand why `RequestContext` is needed during the setup. Though I knew you're the lib creator :p

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods we should first describe to understand how persisting works in MikroORM: `em.persist()` and `em.flush()`.

`em.persist(entity, flush?: boolean)` is used to mark new entities for future persisting. It will make the entity managed by given `EntityManager` and once flush is called, it will be written to the database. The second boolean parameter can be used to invoke the flush immediately. Its default value is configurable via `autoFlush` option.

To understand `flush`, lets first define what managed entity is: an entity is managed if it’s fetched from the database (via `em.find()`, `em.findOne()` or via another managed entity) or registered as new through `em.persist()`.

`em.flush()` will go through all managed entities, compute appropriate change sets and perform according database queries. As an entity loaded from the database becomes managed automatically, you do not have to call `persist` on those, and `flush` is enough to update them.

```
const book = await orm.em.findOne(Book, 1);
book.title = 'How to persist things...';

// no need to persist `book` as its already managed by the EM
await orm.em.flush();
```

Comment: it seems irrelevant to my question but thanks for some info about persist and flush.

Answer (score 0):

When you persist entities, the EM will be maintaining that entity and will keep it in memory. If you're running something like a batch job where you're inserting millions of rows then the EM will be maintaining millions of entities and you may run into out of memory issues (OOM). To prevent running into OOM issues you'll want to run `em.clear()`